# Using other type than serial integer for Activerecord primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, primary-key, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

My data models often require their primary key to be another type than just a vanilla auto-incrementing integer. However, Rails/AR makes it not totally clear how to change that as the default.

How can I use another type than integer as my primary key in Activerecord?

Answer (score 1):

*Caveat: Apart from Rails Master (yet unreleased—PR #18228), `schema.rb` won't remember the column type, so the feature isn't working for the moment. Workarounds are described [here](http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-override-default-primary-key-id-in-rails/).*

I was looking at documentation today as this is something I've been struggling with for a long time, and I came across [`t.primary_key`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-primary_key):

> #### `primary_key(name, type = :primary_key, options = {})`
>
> Appends a primary key definition to the table definition. Can be called multiple times, but this is probably not a good idea.

So you just have to specify your migration as such, with `id: false`, and your primary key with the name and type of your choice:

```
class CreateTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tags, id: false do |t|
      t.primary_key :name, :string

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    # Alternative awkward-er syntax
    # create_table "tags", primary_key: "name", id: "string" do
  end
end
```

Your model will even automagically infer the primary key column name from the schema. Yay!